# Calling Spring boot api that downloads a pdf from Angular 6 is giving error can't parse response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a spring boot API that creates a pdf report and download it, if I call the API directly in the browser, the pdf is created and downloaded directly, but when I call that GET API from Angular 6 I get the following error:

The Spring boot (java) code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app_report/en", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getEnRpt(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("appNum") String appNum) throws JRException, IOException, SQLException {

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("./src/main/resources/jasperReports/App_created_en.jrxml");

    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("P_APP_NO", appNum);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);

    response.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=App_report_en.pdf");

    final OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outStream);
}
```

The Angular code that calls the API:( I tried multiple ways, two are shown here):

```
this.http.get(this.api_url + reportUrl, {
  responseType: 'blob'
}, ).subscribe((response: File) => {
  console.log('report is downloaded');
});

this.http.get(this.api_url + reportUrl).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    console.log('report is downloaded');
  });
```

The console error that I get after the Angular calls the API:

```
error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad 
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://localhost:7001/reports/app_report/en?appNum=xxxxxxx"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "https://localhost:7001/reports/app_report/en?appNum=xxxxxx"
```

I only need to call the API like the call that happens in the browser so that the pdf is downloaded right away

The response headers are as follows:

```
Content-disposition 
inline; filename=App_report_en.pdf
Content-Type    
application/x-pdf
```

Why Angular is not downloading the file like what happens in the browser if I call that API? (especially since the request is successful)

Comment: It's missing your angular code. Most likely, you need to change `responseType` to 'blob' in the request's options

Comment: sorry I forgot to put the angular code, basically I am calling the api with the httpClient.get method and subscribe to it logging the response, I tried using the type as blob but I got no errors without saving the file, I will add the code asap but I can't now

Comment: @David I have added the Angular code, unfortunately even having the responseType as 'blob' didn't help, it only helped avoid the json parsing error but the file was not downloaded, note that calling the api in browser can download automatically the file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid the JSON parsing issue, you need to tell the http client that the response will be a blob, using `responseType: 'blob'` in requests options.

Then, to actually have the navigator open the file, you can follow the instructions from [this blog](https://medium.com/@radicalloop/download-file-using-ajax-in-angular-4-50109564bf17)

```
    const fileName = "report.pdf";
    this.http.get(this.api_url + reportUrl, {  responseType: 'blob'})
    .subscribe((blob: Blob) => {
    console.log('report is downloaded');

    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) 
    { 
        // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else 
    {
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        if (link.download !== undefined) 
        {
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute("href", url);
            link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
        else
        {
            //html5 download not supported
        }
    }   
});
```

This should work for IE 10+ and other modern browsers, apart from iOs (see [CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will try this, I wonder if there any way to call the API directly from Angular like how it is called from the browser? or you think we must use this workaround?

Comment: You could also just have a link that opens the url in a new tab, that may work

Comment: Thanks a million David, your solution works brilliantly

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Boot + Jaspersoft + Angular**

In component.ts

```
reportGenerate() {
this.reportService.generateReport(this.form.value).subscribe(response => {
  let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
  a.setAttribute('target', 'blank');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = response.filename;
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  a.remove();
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

}

In service.ts

```
   public generateReport(data: Data) {
   
    return this.httpService.getReport(url, data)
      .pipe(map((response) => {
        return {
          filename: 'report.pdf',
          data: new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' })
        };
      }));
  }
```

call rest api

```
    getReport(url: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.tokenStoreService.getToken()
        })
        return this.http.post(this.URL + url, data, { headers, responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json'});
 }
```

Spring Boot

```
public JasperReport getJasperReport(String reportJrxml) throws Exception {
     Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(reportJrxml);
     InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
     JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);

    return JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
}
```